# "print" syntax invalid in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, sublimetext3

When using Sublime Text, invalid syntax is showing. But online editor like hackerearth interactive editor does not show any errors as well as python shell command is also okay.

sublime text 3.2.2

python 3.6

print(result[i], end =" ")

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In online Editor

```
def selection_sort(arr, n, x):        
    for i in range(x):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[min_idx] > arr[j]:
                min_idx = j

        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
    return arr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n, x = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))[:n]
    result = selection_sort(arr, n, x)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i], end=" ")
```

In Sublime text:

```
def selection_sort(arr, n, x):
   for i in range(x):
       min_idx = i
       for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
           if arr[min_idx] > arr[j]:
             min_idx = j

       arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
   return arr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n, x = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))[:n]
    result = selection_sort(arr, n, x)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        print(result[i], end =" ")
```

Comment: In your sublime version, you have a space in `end =" "`. This is still valid Python code, but it's possible that sublime syntax checked for Python doesn't allow spaces there? I'm now looking at the file defining python syntax in sublime but I never worked with sublime before.

Comment: end=" " or end = " " both are valid in python3.6, and I tried both way... but same error in sublime text . In terminal, it's working fine...

Comment: I know it's both valid, I said it. ;) I just thought maybe Sublime can't handle it correctly. But it looks like it's been handled correctly for years: `'(?={{identifier}}\s*=(?!=))'`, so the only other suggestion I have is checking whether Sublime really uses your Python3.6 - sometimes interpreters get mixed in IDEs.

Comment: Sublime is never going to print a message like "Syntax Error"; if it doesn't like your code, then it will appear as red in the editor (or some other color based on your color scheme). The fact that you're seeing an error message means that you're seeing the error when you run the code, which is not a Sublime issue. Sublime just executes `python` to ask it to run the code, and that is likely version 2 of Python and not Version 3, so your code is not running like you expect. If you're writing Python 3 specific code, you need to tell Sublime to use that version to run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both python 2 and 3 then it can cause issue.
Try

```py
import sys
sys.version
```

Check if it is version 3

Answer (score 1):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/

```
# This Python program must be run with 
# Python 3 as it won't work with 2.7. 

# ends the output with '@' 
print("Python" , end = '@')  
print("GeeksforGeeks")
```

> Only works with python 3

I did try your program with sublime text.. Works with python 3 and not with python 2.. So you should definitely check what `version of python your calling the function with`

Comment: it's python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the Version and There is slight Syntax change for Version 2 and 3. Which has to consider when we are coding.. 
Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `from __future__ import print_function` to insulate against Python 2 vs 3 issues in this case.  See [https://docs.python.org/2/library/**future**.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) for details.